# Bayesian Model Averaging (Bayesian Averaging of Classical Estimates) Issue

Tags: regression, time-series, bayesian, model-averaging, forecast-combination

[I am trying to implement a method used by this paper (Described briefly at the bottom of page 3):](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/5112109_Model_Uncertainty_Thick_Modelling_and_the_Predictability_of_Stock_Returns)

From what I understand, it does 2$^k$ OLS regressions each time step to forecast the next time step for **k** regressors (9 in this case excluding the constant term); then it compares the best model (thin model) according to its Adjusted-R$^2$ with other %x best models (Page7_TABLE 1).

So, it does 512 regressions at each time-step, gets the best model (let's say [1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1] 1st, 4th, 7th, 9th regressors are included in the model) and compares it with combination of best %2.5, %5, %7.5 ...  adjusted-R$^2$ models according to some criterion (PT-DM-Reality Check). The combination of models uses a method called Bayesian Estimates of Classical Estimates.

[Described in this paper](http://www.vcharite.univ-mrs.fr/PP/lubrano/BMC/Sala-i-Martin-Long-term-growth-AER-2004.pdf)

[Replication package and how they implemented the BACE can be found here](https://www.openicpsr.org/openicpsr/project/116024/version/V1/view;jsessionid=268520C9F036B9DF165D4F121853EFB6)

The second paper and general model averaging papers generally describes getting the **posterior inclusion probabilities**, **posterior mean conditional on inclusion** etc.

What I don't understand is how do you combine the models.

Let's say I did 512 OLS regressions and sorted them according to their adjusted-r$^2$, we got the best model [1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1], and we want to compare it with other 511 models.

[1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1] **vs.** [1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0], [1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1], [1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1] ... and so on.

I have got several questions after this step:

The literature I went through generally describes the inclusion probabilities and other statistics according to **each variable**; but how can I create a **combined model** from that information?

What will my combined model look like? Let's say for the best %2.5 of the models will I have something like **0.3 of model 2**, **0.4 of model 3**, **0.04 of model 4** ...?

Because the first paper on page 7 compares combination of %x of best models (thick model) with a single model (thin model); but I can't just wrap my head around what the combined model means or how can you get a combined model from inclusion probabilities of several regressors?

I highly appreciate your help and would appreciate if you can direct me to another source (especially code implementation) even if you can't or don't have time to explain the questions. Thank you.